# один запрос по двум параметрам

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'SELECT * FROM `friend` WHERE `uid` = '.$_SESSION['id'].' AND `inactive` = 1 AND `inid` = '.$_SESSION['id'].' AND `unactive` = 1 ');
```

Мне нужно чтобы оно выаскивало все строки в которых:

> или SESSION['id'] = uid и `inactive` = 1
>   или SESSION['id'] = inid и `unactive` = 1

сейчас у меня возвращает только одну запись(

Comment: или обозначается как OR, то что с И заключайте в скобки

Comment: можно поконкретней?
мне нужно чобы и по тому правилу и по второму оображало)
тоесть из ехи двух или SESSION['id'] = uid и inactive = 1

или SESSION['id'] = inid и unactive = 1

Comment: вот берете вашу фразу `SESSION['id'] = uid и inactive = 1 или SESSION['id'] = inid и unactive = 1` и переводите  на английский. `(SESSION['id'] = uid и inactive = 1) OR (SESSION['id'] = inid и unactive = 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем ИЛИ условие

```
SELECT * FROM `friend` WHERE (`uid` = '.$_SESSION['id'].' AND `inactive` = 1 ) OR (`inid` = '.$_SESSION['id'].' AND `unactive` = 1)
```

Comment: в твоем коде оно ищет сесию в uid или inid а мне нужно чтобы оно при етом сверяло где uid = '.$_SESSION['id'].' и inactive = 1 и наоборот

Comment: еше один вопрос)
оно будет олько один вариант возвращать?

Comment: Сколько найдет столько и вернет. Чтобы возвращало не более одного результата надо в конец запроса добавить ` LIMIT 1`

Comment: спасибо за помощь)